# Excel Not Showing Formula After Fn+F9 Evaluation of the Part of the Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

After evaluating part of the formula in Excel by pressing Fn+F9 I pressed Enter and got the final result. I wanted to go back and check the formula, but I noticed that the formula does not contain the previously evaluated part as formula but as value.

How can I bring back my formula???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to Undo the last action. The **Undo** will work unless the file has been saved.
- press <kbd>Escape</kbd>, before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or stepping away from the formula cell.

Comment: On a side note, `Ctrl + Z` will stop working once the file is saved. Sorry for stating the obvious... just want to make sure the users are careful enough.